# Poor suggestions in SolR Spellcheck 1.3

Tags: java, solr, config, spell-checking

I implemented spellcheck searchComponent in my SolR 1.3 project, and it works.

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
<lst name="spellchecker">
<str name="name">default</str>
<str name="field">DRETITLE</str>
<str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
<float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
<int name="minPrefix">1</int>
<int name="minQueryLength">3</int>
</lst>
</searchComponent>
```

But suggestions don't work as expected... For example:

If I search **bosa** (wrong word) the expected suggestion will be **bossa** (Catalan language) but SpellCheck doesn't find any suggestions.

If I search **acsa** the expected suggestion will be **casa** but SpellCheck doesn't find any suggestions.

This configuriation works well for basic suggestions, but that's all.For example:

If I search **treballaior** It returns me **treballador** so it's ok. But if I search **trballaior** it returns me **ballador**. So, where are letters *t* and *r*? The most correct suggestion would be **treballador**.

It sounds like my SpellCheck component does not consider the possibility of write words in wrong order.
I have tried different configurations but it works the same way.

Is it a configuration problem or is it because the version I use is too old?

Comment: Upgrading Solr should at least be your first step - 1.3 is nine years old! Also, when using the Direct spell checker, the analysis sequence on your fields will be very important as it compares the terms against the tokens after analysis. There's [a lot of documentation available](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spell+Checking) for the current spellcheck functionality.